# getting "Authentication credentials were not provided." ERROR in vue quasar

Tags: python, vue.js, quasar-framework

i am using api calls to get students profile and it gets the url correctly but with an authentication error .it would be great if can help me.

```
async studentShow() {
  await this.$axios.get(this.$serverUrls.showStudent)
  .then(response => {
  if (response.status === 'error') return
  this.studentList = response.data
  })
  .catch((error) => {
  if (error.response.status == 400) {
  this.$q.notify({
    color: "negative",
    position: "top",
    message: "شماره تکراری است",
    icon: "report_problem",
  });
  } else {
  this.$q.notify({
    color: "negative",
    position: "top",
    message: "مشکل در اتصال",
    icon: "report_problem",
  });
}
```

});

```
},
```

above is code in my component

```
Vue.prototype.$serverUrls['registerPerson'] = 'auth/users/register_person/';
Vue.prototype.$serverUrls['createParent'] = 'school/parent/';
Vue.prototype.$serverUrls['showStudent'] = 'school/student/';
```

code in quasar boot -> urls.js

and the error it gets

```
detail: "Authentication credentials were not provided."
```